# How do I increase/decrease the pitch via ffmpeg while still maintaining the audio duration?

Tags: android, flutter, ffmpeg, audio-processing

I'm using a flutter plugin called FFMpegKit to raise/lower the pitch of an audio input. I've tried a few different things, but with each attempt there is a different problem. The goal is to raise/lower the pitch while keeping the same audio duration.

**Attempt #1:** this worked ok, but the problem is that the output audio quality seems lower/worse than the input audio

```
await FFmpegKit.executeAsync('-i ' + 'input.mp3' + ' -af asetrate=8000*1.5,aresample=8000,atempo=1/1.5 ' + 'output.mp3', ffmpegCallbackHigh);
```

**Attempt #2:** the problem here is that the the audio duration is significantly shortened, so much so that you can't hear any of the words being said

```
await FFmpegKit.executeAsync('-i ' + 'input.mp3' + ' -af asetrate=44100*1.5,aresample=44100,atempo=1/1.5 ' + 'output.mp3', ffmpegCallbackHigh);
```

Comment: I don't know anything about *FFmpeg* specifically, but natural-sounding pitch shifting needs advanced algorithms, and it can be (relatively) computationally intensive. So you might only have the weird-sounding results available. From a quick search people recommend a version of *FFmpeg* compiled with a library called *librubberband* (a time/pitch-stretching library written to get these better results) but I don't know what's available to you. Hopefully someone will have some advice on the settings you could use here, I just wanted to mention the potential limitations

Comment: @cactustictacs hmm...yea sounds like it might have potential, but the catch is that this will be running on end users' phones. Not sure if I can deploy with too many libraries...idk

Comment: `ffmpeg` itself has https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-rubberband which I assume  you can access from FFMpegKit